# VSTS NuGet Publishing Using REST

Tags: rest, azure-devops, nuget, devops

For our internal tooling, we need to interact with VSTS NuGet feeds programmatically. At this point, I am trying to replace using `nuget.exe` as a command line with the REST API to [DevOps REST Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) services.

I can get pretty much everything working via REST, including downloading packages, except for publishing. What am I missing? Is publishing to the feed supported via REST?

Additionally, any advice as to how to create a NuGet package programmatically without using `nuget.exe` is greatly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I'm not actually sure if it is possible currently to publish packages via REST, I've only seen documentation for using something like nuget.exe. Why are you replacing using nuget.exe? I don't think I've seen a way to upload a package via the UI, but if there is some way to do that, you could always use Fiddler to capture the API call.

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddler idea! As for why we are replacing nuget.exe, considering that our internal tool implements some custom steps during the build process and needs to publish the artifacts, it's seems much cleaner to do it natively in proc rather than run nuget.exe in a separate process and capture the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is publishing to the feed supported via REST?

I am afraid the answer is no. As we know, REST API usually takes advantage of HTTP when used for Web APIs.

Since there is no option on the web UI to publish nuget to the Artifacts, so, there is no such REST API to publish nuget package to the Artifacts. But you could push NuGet package programmatically using NuGet.Core, install NuGet.Core NuGet package in your project and add NuGet namespace to your using statements.

Check the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549645/push-nuget-package-programmatically-using-nuget-core/26551044#26551044) for some more details.

> how to create a NuGet package programmatically without using nuget.exe
>   is greatly appreciated.

Yes, you could also use NuGet Core APIs to create NuGet package programmatically, check the following document:

[Play with Packages, programmatically!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/play-with-packages/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like Nuget.Core is no longer supported. Is there a recommended replacement?